Inverse Hyperbolic Transformation of Dependent Variable
I am trying to transform a dependent variable which is a measure of time (minutes per day). To account for zero values of the dependent variable in the regression, I am taking its inverse hyperbolic transformation. Can anyone tell me how I can interpret the coefficient? My independent variable is a dummy.

Hi: I've never used them ( and don't know much about them )  but another approach is zero-inflated models. These really depend on the underlying distribution assumed for the response. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model

In practice, econometricians just interpret it as if the regressor had the natural log transformation. "The approximate average change in the outcome that is associated with the regressor increasing 100%."
This interpretation is an approximation even with the log transformation. It's just more of an approximation with the inverse hyperbolic sine transformation.
EDIT:
If you care, a recent paper that does this is https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20201015
The math is,



that's interesting. thank you.

Thanks so much! This helps a lot
